# I am trying to fill a Customer Model with rows from a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I am trying to fill a Customer Model with rows from a datatable but have not been able to get the syntax correct. The original code was taken from this tutorial [Your First ASP.NET Web API (C#](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)).

I have added a DataTable to a Controller but I have not been able to figure out how to get the rows from the table into my Customer Model. I thoought I could do it with a foreach but as I said I can't get the syntax correct. This is what I have

```
    Customer[] customers = new Customer[]
    {
        //new Customer {Id = "123", FirstName = "Buk", LastName = "Hix" }
        // Replace hard coded customer information with foreach loop.

        //commented out because it causes compile warnings
        //foreach (DataRow row in GetAllData().Rows)
        //{
        //    yield return new Customer
        //    {
        //        CustomerId = Convert.ToString(row["CustomerId"]),
        //        FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["FirstName"]),
        //        LastName = Convert.ToString(row["LastName"])
        //    };
        //}
    };

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {            
        return customers;
    }
```

What is the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  When creating an iterator (a function that returns an IEnumerable/IEnumerator that uses `yield`), you just put the code in the body to `yield` the values as necessary.  No need to throw them into another collection.  The compiler will generate an iterator for the code.

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    foreach (DataRow row in GetAllData().Rows)
    {
        yield return new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = row.Field<string>("CustomerId"),
            FirstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName"),
            LastName = row.Field<string>("LastName"),
        };
    }
}
```

It would be nicer to use LINQ here though if you're open to it.

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    return
        from row in GetAllData().Rows
        select new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = row.Field<string>("CustomerId"),
            FirstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName"),
            LastName = row.Field<string>("LastName"),
        };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run I am not getting any results back. And in debugging I set a break point on the IEnumerable and it is not even hitting it. Do I need to do anything else to make sure that gets called?

Comment: If you don't hit any breakpoints within the loop, that would mean the Rows you get back is empty.  Can you verify that the `DataTable` (?) you get back actually contains data?

Comment: Is my problem releated to  the JavaScript expecting   $.getJSON("api/customers/", and I am now returning Customer (select new customer)

Comment: I am not even hitting the foreach for the datarow either so I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: I personally haven't worked with ASP.net to know how making web calls worked so I wouldn't be the best person to ask whether the javascript is causing the problem or not.  Again, verify that you're actually getting data first because the code here should work fine returning data if there was any to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ:

```
Customer[] customers = GetAllData()
    .Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new Customer
    {
        CustomerId = Convert.ToString(row["CustomerId"]),
        FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["FirstName"]),
        LastName = Convert.ToString(row["LastName"])
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Make sure that you have added `System.Linq` to your `using` directives to bring the extension methods in scope.